# How to disable the UIView in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

How to disable the UIView in iPhone?

Comment: Not visible or no interactions ?

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense....

Comment: This question does not make any sense indeed. What do you mean with disable? Disable user input, make it invisible, remove it from its superview? Please clarify.

Answer (score 7):

```
view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: How about view.hidden = YES; ;)

Comment: It depends on what you need to do. To disable it, you would use userInteractionEnabled, but for hiding it, you would use hidden. It is case-dependent.

Comment: there could be one more [view removeFromSuperView]; but @Praveen S is more accurate.

Comment: I think question needs more clarification.

Comment: Subviews can still get touches or gesture recognizers in my experience